# How to Display DropDownList selected Item value i.e. TextField/value to GridView?

Tags: asp.net

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCaKE.jpg)[This is a webpage I have designed][2]

Its an ASP.NET Webpage  using SQL server database. As u can see in  grid view class column displays SelectedItemValues but ,I want to show Values of Class not ID's  i.e. MCA,MBA etc. Dropdown ctrl is used for accepting Class Field in form.

There r two tables in my database, Student and ClassDetail. Student table have foreign key constraints over ClassDetail table. N classeDetail table is bind with Drop down list control . So how I can achieve it! I cant store text value to database. Bcoz ClassDetail has relationship with multiple table.

Answer (score 0):

Check your select statment, if the class is a lookup table in the database this means you need to add more join in your select query.  If not you can add case statment in your select to return the required text for each number.